# AngularJS get string from JSON file

Tags: json, angularjs

I have got a JSON file with this structure

```
"entities": [
    {
      "id": ,
      "signature": "",
      "title": "",
      "nr": "",
      "class_name": "",
      "tags": [
        {
          "tag_type_id": "",
          "tag_type_name": "",
          "value": ""
        }
      ],
      "attachments": [
        {
          "file_name": "",
          "type": ""
        },
        {
          "file_name": "",
          "type": ""
        }
      ],
      "photo": []
    },
```

I want to display only a file_name in a `<img src="file_name">` to display this image.
I'm using a ng-repeat to display a content a title from entities but how to display also a file_name?

Comment: `entities[0].attchments[1].file_name`

Comment: @tymeJV But how to do this for a list entites with ng-repeat?

Comment: Can you give exact structure of json or use ng-repeat here is the link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: use ng-repeat for data.attachment `image in data.attachment` `<img src=image.file_name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7PqHaa7sEivJbcekTeUx?p=preview

```
   <div ng-repeat="ent in entities">
      <img ng-repeat="img in ent.attachments" ng-src="{{img.file_name}}" />
    </div>
```